# How to update a security group using lambda function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to update AWS security group with one inbound rules using lambda function Python 3.7. For example: I would like to add my public IP with 8443 Port in existing security group. I have followed below link to achieve.

[Modifying ec2 security group using lambda function](https://griggheo.medium.com/modifying-ec2-security-groups-via-aws-lambda-functions-115a1828cdb6)

When I used this code on Lambda function with Python 3.7, it's not working.

```
import boto3
import hashlib
import json
import copy
import urllib2

# ID of the security group we want to update
SECURITY_GROUP_ID = "sg-XXXX"

# Description of the security rule we want to replace
SECURITY_RULE_DESCR = "My Home IP"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    new_ip_address = list(event.values())[0]
    result = update_security_group(new_ip_address)
    return result

def update_security_group(new_ip_address):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    response = client.describe_security_groups(GroupIds=[SECURITY_GROUP_ID])
    group = response['SecurityGroups'][0]
    for permission in group['IpPermissions']:
        new_permission = copy.deepcopy(permission)
        ip_ranges = new_permission['IpRanges']
        for ip_range in ip_ranges:
            if ip_range['Description'] == 'My Home IP':
                ip_range['CidrIp'] = "%s/32" % new_ip_address
        client.revoke_security_group_ingress(GroupId=group['GroupId'], IpPermissions= 
        [permission])
        client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=group['GroupId'], IpPermissions= 
        [new_permission])
        
        return ""
```

I got response as `""`, when I tested this code on lambda function.

Comment: So, how do you use this code on lambda?

Comment: I just followed this link. https://griggheo.medium.com/modifying-ec2-security-groups-via-aws-lambda-functions-115a1828cdb6. Cant I use this code on Lambda function? Can you please correct me if i'm wrong?

Comment: Isn't it simply that your `return ""` statement is incorrectly indented?

Comment: Yes. Incorrect indent. Now its running. But inbound rules not added. Can you please check this python code?

Comment: Is my question wrong? No one answer to my question. Am i wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You wrote `return ""`. Did you expect something different to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`revoke_security_group_ingress()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.revoke_security_group_ingress) and [`authorize_security_group_ingress()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.authorize_security_group_ingress) calls in boto3 includes a `Return` field in the `response`:

> Returns `true` if the request succeeds; otherwise, returns an error.

However, your code does not seem to be storing a `response` or examining its contents.

Comment: I hope we can use security_group_ingress () to update inbound rules to an existing security group